# Modify the data type of last layer of transformer model - llama huggingface

Tags: python, torch, huggingface

I'm using torch to load the `decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf` from hf, which is a `'transformers.models.llama.modeling_llama.LlamaForCausalLM'` and the only way I manage to load it is by using `load_in_8bit`.

because of that, when I try to do inferences with the model I get:

```
RuntimeError: "log_softmax_lastdim_kernel_impl" not implemented for 'Half'
```

How can I change the number of bits of the last layer of the model to prevent that error?